# Ruby "defined?" operator works wrong?

Tags: ruby, exception, behavior, defined

So, we have the code:

```
class Foo
  def bar
    puts "Before existent: #{(defined? some_variable)}"
    puts "Before not_existent: #{(defined? nonexistent_variable)}"

    raise "error"

    some_variable = 42
  rescue
    puts "exception"
  ensure
    puts "Ensure existent: #{(defined? some_variable)}"
    puts "Ensure not_existent: #{(defined? nonexistent_variable)}"
  end
end
```

And call it from irb:

```
> Foo.new.bar
```

And, that is will return:

```
Before existent:
Before not_existent:
exception
Ensure existent: local-variable
Ensure not_existent:
=> nil
```

And now is question - why? We raised exception *before* than `some_variable` be defined. 
Why it works this way? Why `some_variable` is defined in ensure block? (btw, it defined as nil)

**UPDATE:**
Thanks @Max for answer, but if we change code to use instance variable:

```
class Foo
  def bar
    puts "Before existent: #{(defined? @some_variable)}"
    puts "Before not_existent: #{(defined? @nonexistent_variable)}"

    raise "error"

    @some_variable = 42
  ensure
    puts "Ensure existent: #{(defined? @some_variable)}"
    puts "Ensure not_existent: #{(defined? @nonexistent_variable)}"
  end
end
```

It works as expected:

```
Before existent:
Before not_existent:
Ensure existent:
Ensure not_existent:
```

Why?

Comment: References to undefined instance (and global) variables are treated differently than those to undefined local (and class) variables. For example, `puts @a #=> nil`, whereas `puts a #NameError: undefined local variable or method `a' for main:Object`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first thing to notice is that `defined?` is a *keyword*, not a method. That means it has its own special [VM instruction](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Aruby/ruby%20DEFINE_INSN&type=code) recognized by the interpreter during parsing when the syntax tree is constructed (just like `if`, `return`, `next`, etc.) rather than dynamically looked up at runtime.

This is why `defined?` can handle expressions that would normally raise an error: `defined?(what is this even) #=> nil` because the parser can exclude its argument from the normal evaluating process.

Even though it is a keyword, its behavior is still determined at runtime. It uses parser magic to determine whether its argument is an instance variable, constant, method, etc. *but then* calls normal Ruby methods to determine whether these specific types have been defined at runtime:

```c
// ...
case DEFINED_GVAR:
if (rb_gvar_defined(rb_global_entry(SYM2ID(obj)))) {
    expr_type = DEFINED_GVAR;
}
break;
case DEFINED_CVAR:
// ...
if (rb_cvar_defined(klass, SYM2ID(obj))) {
    expr_type = DEFINED_CVAR;
}
break;
case DEFINED_CONST:
// ...
if (vm_get_ev_const(th, klass, SYM2ID(obj), 1)) {
    expr_type = DEFINED_CONST;
}
break;
// ...
```

That `rb_cvar_defined` function is the same one called by [`Module#class_variable_defined?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Module.html#method-i-class_variable_defined-3F), for example.

So `defined?` is weird. Really weird. Its behavior could vary a lot depending on its argument, and I wouldn't even bet on it being the same across different Ruby implementations. Based on this I would recommend not using it and instead use Ruby's `*_defined?` methods wherever possible.

Comment: Wow. Thats weird. Do you have some doc or details about it?