# Using defined? in a Ternary operator

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to clean up my code from this...

```
<% if defined? foo == "local-variable" %>
    <% foo = foo %>
<% else %>
    <% foo = nil %>
<% end %>
```

To use a ternary operator like so...

```
<% defined? foo == "local-variable" ? foo : nil %>
```

However the ternary does not run properly and defaults to the `nil` ... I'm rather new to using ternary operators (may have gotten into the habit of using them since they save lines)... is using `defined?` in a ternary possible?

Comment: BTW, your second statement is not equivalent to the first - the assignment is missing, i.e. `foo` is not set to `nil`.

Comment: Is there really a need for `foo = foo` ?

Comment: @limekin no there is not I am more inclined to suggest `<% foo=nil unless local_variable_defined?(foo) %>` or as @PiotrKruczek suggested `<% foo ||= nil %>` but either way these do not pertain to the question. Also I have no idea about the implementation here or why this logic must exist in a view rather than a controller or model.

Comment: Also considering that == is a method, and method calls in Ruby are evaluated from right to left,  I think in your initial code `foo == 'local-variable'` is evaluated first giving `false` and then `defined? false` gets evaluated which makes the if condition return true always.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be:

```
<% defined?(foo) == "local-variable" ? foo : nil %>
```

[`From documentation`](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html#method-i-defined-3F):

> ... return value provides information about the expression.

```
>> defined?(foo) == "local-variable"
=> true
>> defined? foo
=> "local-variable"
>> defined? (foo == "local-variable")
=> "method"
```

[`Ruby operator precedence`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/doc/syntax/precedence_rdoc.html)

Comment: Ahh perfect I was just forgetting the parenthesis. Thanks!

Comment: You can use `local_variable_defined?(:foo)` instead of `defined?(foo) == "local-variable"`

Comment: `defined?` should be avoided unless you know exactly what you're doing. Since you're just using it for a local variable, I agree with @Stefan's recommendation. See my answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29371966/ruby-defined-operator-works-wrong/29372162#29372162) for some of the problems with `defined?`

Answer (score 2):

That's not exactly an answer to your question, but something like this may help:

```
foo ||= nil
```

Translates to:

```
if defined? foo
  foo || foo = nil
else
  foo = nil
end
```

Comment: That's not *precisely* true. That translates to `if (foo)` which means `foo` could be either `false` or `nil`. There was talk of adding `//=` which meant exactly what you're talking about here but I'm not sure where that proposal got to.